# How I fix this error? Specific port is in use

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I want to start my web application in Visual Studio 2013, but it is not starting. It is showing me an error Port "2729" is in use. Which is the port number of my Web Application. Please guide me. How can I start my application which has 2729 port number.

Comment: Stop the previous version that is still running?

Comment: @Martin James, My problem is solved now by changing the "port number".